# How to get file name in gtk_recent_chooser_dialog_new widget

Tags: c#, gtk3

How to get the name of the selected file in gtk_recent_chooser_dialog_new widget. Below a demo file to explain.....

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
//recentchooserdialog.c
/*
gcc -std=c11 -Wall -fmax-errors=10 -Wextra recentchooserdialog.c -o recentchooserdialog `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 `
*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    gboolean multiple = FALSE;
    //GList * files;
    GtkRecentInfo *info;
    gchar *chemin = NULL;

    GtkWidget *recentchooserdialog = gtk_recent_chooser_dialog_new("RecentChooserDialog", NULL, 
                            ("_Cancel"), GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL, 
                            ("_Open"), GTK_RESPONSE_OK, NULL);

    gtk_recent_chooser_set_limit(GTK_RECENT_CHOOSER(recentchooserdialog),-1);
    gtk_recent_chooser_set_show_tips(GTK_RECENT_CHOOSER(recentchooserdialog),TRUE);
    gtk_recent_chooser_set_select_multiple(GTK_RECENT_CHOOSER(recentchooserdialog), multiple);

    if (gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(recentchooserdialog)) == GTK_RESPONSE_OK)
    {
        info = gtk_recent_chooser_get_current_item (GTK_RECENT_CHOOSER (recentchooserdialog));
        if (multiple==TRUE)
        {
            /** how to get file names selected here **/

        }
        else
        {
            /** how to get one single filename selected here **/
            // GtkRecentInfo *info;
            info = gtk_recent_chooser_get_current_item (GTK_RECENT_CHOOSER (recentchooserdialog));
            if (info)
                g_print("structur info exists\n ");
            /* below is not the good casting */
            chemin = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(recentchooserdialog));
            g_print("selected path %s\n",chemin);
        }
        gtk_recent_info_unref (info);
    }
    gtk_widget_destroy (recentchooserdialog);
    return 0;
}
```

after many googled action.... I didn't find any thing
On the over hand in gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new I found

gtk_file_chooser_get_filename or gtk_file_chooser_get_filenames action 
below the other context is ok for me

```
void cb_open (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *dialog = NULL;
  GtkFileChooserAction action = GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN;

  dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new ("Ouvrir un fichier", NULL,
                                          action,
                                          ("_Cancel"),
                                          GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,
                                          ("_Open"),
                                          GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,
                                          NULL);

  if (gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (dialog)) == GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT)
  {
    gchar *file_name = NULL;

    file_name = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename (GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (dialog));
    g_print("fichier ouvert : %s \n",file_name);

    g_free (file_name), file_name = NULL;
  }
  gtk_widget_destroy (dialog);
}
```

Could you help me to complete single selection and multiple selection case
Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

A [GtkRecentChooserDialog](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkRecentChooserDialog.html) does **not** implement the [GtkFileChooser](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html) interface.

A recent file chooser dialog does implement the [GtkRecentChooser](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkRecentChooser.html) interface, though, which means you can use [`gtk_recent_chooser_get_current_item()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkRecentChooser.html#gtk-recent-chooser-get-current-item) to retrieve the currently selected recent file, and then use the [`GtkRecentInfo`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkRecentManager.html#GtkRecentInfo) API to retrieve things like [the URI](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkRecentManager.html#gtk-recent-info-get-uri) or [the icon](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkRecentManager.html#gtk-recent-info-get-gicon) of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I found a part of solution for  single selection

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
//recentchooserdialog.c
/*
gcc -std=c11 -Wall -fmax-errors=10 -Wextra recentchooserdialog.c -o recentchooserdialog `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 `
*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    gboolean multiple = FALSE;
    //GList * files;
    GtkRecentInfo *info;
    const gchar *text_info = NULL;

    GtkWidget *recentchooserdialog = gtk_recent_chooser_dialog_new("RecentChooserDialog", NULL, 
                            ("_Cancel"), GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL, 
                            ("_Open"), GTK_RESPONSE_OK, NULL);

    gtk_recent_chooser_set_limit(GTK_RECENT_CHOOSER(recentchooserdialog),-1);
    gtk_recent_chooser_set_show_tips(GTK_RECENT_CHOOSER(recentchooserdialog),TRUE);
    gtk_recent_chooser_set_select_multiple(GTK_RECENT_CHOOSER(recentchooserdialog), multiple);

    if (gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(recentchooserdialog)) == GTK_RESPONSE_OK)
    {
        info = gtk_recent_chooser_get_current_item (GTK_RECENT_CHOOSER (recentchooserdialog));
        if (multiple==TRUE)
        {
            /** how to get file names selected here **/

        }
        else
        {
            /** how to get one single filename selected here **/
            info = gtk_recent_chooser_get_current_item (GTK_RECENT_CHOOSER (recentchooserdialog));
            if (info)
            {
                text_info = gtk_recent_info_get_uri (info);
                g_print("une structure info existe %s\n", text_info);
            }
        }
        gtk_recent_info_unref (info);
    }
    gtk_widget_destroy (recentchooserdialog);
    return 0;
}
```

be carefull with unicode string
I dont test what is the good action must added

```
text_info = g_locale_to_utf8 (text_info, -1, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

or

```
text_info = g_locale_from_utf8 (text_info, -1, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

next step is to test what is about for multiple selection